# How do I change visibility of a textbox inside a ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I have a report viewer, and in a given circumstance, I want to change the visibility of a textbox inside the report viewer.
I already changed the name of the textbox, but I cant access the textbox from outside.

I tried this (which not compile):

```
myReportViewer.txbPI.Visible = false
```

What should I do please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an expression for the `Hidden` property of the textbox and hide it based on the value of a data item (if you bind the report to a data source) or report parameter.

[image]